# CSRF Token not working in Laravel 5.1 Exceptions Handler with an Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 application with Ajax content loaded at start up.

I have placed the CSRF meta tag to page head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And I use it in jquery ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
  headers:
  {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
  }
});
```

Everything works perfectly under normal circumstances. But when I open a 404 error page without a previous session, my ajax requests get an error:
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

I have an 404 error handler in file: app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
  if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
  {
    $foo = \App\Foo::foo();
    return \Response::make(view("errors.404", compact("foo")), 404);
  }

  return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

I can repeat this error by opening a private browser window and opening my site with an url to a non existing page. It persists on page reloads. But if I go to an existing page and try the 404 url again, it works fine.

Any ideas how fix this problem?

EDIT:

I tried checking multiple ajax requests and it seems like every request has a complitely different session with different token:

```
$request->session()->token();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSRF middleware add this before return parent::handle($request, $next):

```
if($request->ajax())
{
    \Input::merge([
        '_token' => $request->header('X-CSRF-Token')
    ]);
}
```

Edit:
Is the csrf_token() returning anything on that 404 page? I found sth interesting [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-crsf-token-returns-null-on-custom-404-page). Looks similar to your problem

Comment: No luck. The Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php function tokensMatch already gets the token by:

$token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

Comment: Yes, csrf_token() is returning a value. I could redirect the user to a separate 404 url and thus avoid the problem. Then the user would lose the original url though. Seems odd that I'd have to do that.